# moving data from long to wide format in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a function to iterate through every row in a dataframe to find matches and then append those matches within the same row, changing the data from long to wide format. I haven't had success with df.pivot, which was my intuition, so I need to try something else.

```
for x in df.itertuples():
    for y in df.itertuples():
        if x.MDS==y.MDS:
```

this is my nested for loop for identifying all of the matches

```
pd.Dataframe=({'MDS': {106: 2, 107: 10, 108: 100, 109: 500, 110: 2}, 'LSR': {106: '3-4', 107: '3-4', 108: '3-4', 109: '3-4', 110: '3-6'}, 'Small State Wins': {106: 4150, 107: 5210, 108: 5405, 109: 5625, 110: 3893}})
```

this is my example dataframe, or just a snapshot of it. I want to find matches in the column MDS, and when there is a match, take that observation and put it into new columns that correspond to the original match.

```
 MDS    LSR    Small State Wins    Match1MDS    Match1LSR    Match1Small State Wins
   2    3-4    4150                2            3-6          4150
  10    3-4    5210                NaN          NaN          NaN
 100    3-4    5405                NaN          NaN          NaN
 500    3-4    5625                NaN          NaN          NaN
   2    3-6    3893                2            3-4          3893
```

Some dataframe like that is my desired outcome. I would prefer to ignore a-to-a matches, insofar that I don't want row 0 to match to row 0 and record in the new columns. I would like to have a blank or no observation if there is not a match found Also, if there are 3 observations that match under the MDS columns, I would like to have them attached in wide format too, under a match2 name, and so on for all matches n. Runtime isn't a problem because the dataset is relatively small, under 10,000 so I can use a nested loop, but I'm really stuck on the shifting the data.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by long and wide format? Are you just trying to transpose the table?

Comment: @Barmar I looked into transposing the table and that isn't quite what I'm looking for. I need to preserve the original rows as is, and transposition just flips them. Long format is all of the observations in rows, and wide format is all of the observations in column format. I see what you mean by your questions but basically the output I need is the dataframe I created at the end

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for.

```
df['group_count'] = df.groupby(
    'MDS',
    group_keys=False,
)['MDS'].expanding().count().reset_index(
    level=0,
    drop=True,
)

df = df.set_index(['MDS', 'group_count']).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Updated comment. when you pass .groupby, it's creating a Multindex so when you call ['MDS'] at the end it can't be found. Any suggestions on how to revert it back?

Comment: I tested with a dataframe created by doing `df = pd.Dataframe({'MDS': {106: 2, 107: 10, 108: 100, 109: 500, 110: 2}, 'LSR': {106: '3-4', 107: '3-4', 108: '3-4', 109: '3-4', 110: '3-6'}, 'Small State Wins': {106: 4150, 107: 5210, 108: 5405, 109: 5625, 110: 3893}})`. If it doesn't work for you on that dataframe, maybe it's a change in behavior across versions of pandas. I'm on version `1.1.3`.

Comment: I think it was a change across pandas versions. I've updated it to work with the latest version of pandas. A little ugly, but it seems to work.